# Downloading a file using luasocket

Tags: lua, download, luasocket

I'm sorry if this has a simple solution, or if this has been resolved before, but I am so far removed from any kind of network programming that I really have no idea what is even wrong nor what to search for to fix it.

I would like to be able to download a json file from "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates" (and other places) using a language I know well, Lua, with the extension, luasocket.

I've tried using `http.request` and `ftp.get`, but neither returns any kind of information. I don't understand why I can go to that url on my browser, and it downloads a file, but I can't get the file data through luasocket. If I cannot use luasocket, then what are the differences between a request made from your web browser and a request made from something like luasocket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may see the URL you have is `https` not plain `http`. You need to use encrypted connection. Use **luasec** for that instead of **luasocket** (actually luasec depends on luasocket but let's not bother for now; in short `https.request` from luasec is built on `http.request` from luasocket).

```
local https = require "ssl.https" --luasec
local r,c,h,s = https.request {
    url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates",
    sink = ltn12.sink.file(io.stdout)
}
```

This will print body of requested content in console.

More about [luasocket's http](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) and [luasec's https](https://github.com/brunoos/luasec/wiki/LuaSec-0.5#https_request).